# How to get the physical display resolution in SDL2?

Tags: sdl, screen-resolution, sdl-2, highdpi

I have tried

```
SDL_DisplayMode DM;
SDL_GetDesktopDisplayMode(0, &DM);
auto Width = DM.w;
auto Height = DM.h;
```

but on a high-DPI display it returns the virtual screen resolution. `SDL_GetCurrentDisplayMode` does the same.

So, how can I get the physical screen size also on high-DPI displays?

Answer (score 1):

The only way seems to be to create a fullscreen `SDL_Window` (passing `SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI` in the flags) and query its "drawable size" with `SDL_GL_GetDrawableSize`.

Comment: You can also use `SDL_GetRendererOutputSize()` on the full screen window.